# Optimising SQL statement to use query but need to reference column outside subquery somehow

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, subquery, ora-00904

Is there any way in Oracle within an SQL query to reference a column from within a subquery that is outside of it, or to achieve that effect even if via a different means? Everything I've read on the web so far has just not helped with this.

For example (this is the kind of thing I'm after):

```
SELECT a.product_code, b.received, b.issued
FROM productinfo a,
 (SELECT SUM(qty_received) AS received, SUM(qty_issued) AS issued
  FROM productdetail b WHERE b.product_code = a.product_code AND active = 1);
```

I've tried loads of different variations/combinationsAt the moment I just get errors like ORA-00904: invalid identifier relating to the WHERE clause relationship.

At present if I run as seperate queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT product_code FROM productinfo;
```

and then for each of those records:

```
SELECT SUM(qty_received) AS received, SUM(qty_issued) AS issued FROM productdetail
WHERE product_code = '(specified)' AND active = 1;
```

This can take over an half an hour to run for 8000 records which is just plain daft.

Running out of hair, any help appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ORA error is because you can't correlate the derived table/inline view - you need to use JOIN notation (ANSI-89 or 92).

Assuming you really need column(s) from the `PRODUCTINFO` table, use:

```
SELECT a.product_code, b.received, b.issued
  FROM PRODUCTINFO a
  JOIN (SELECT t.product_code,
               SUM(t.qty_received) AS received, 
               SUM(t.qty_issued) AS issued
          FROM PRODUCTDETAIL t 
         WHERE t.active = 1
      GROUP BY t.produce_code) b ON b.product_code = a.product_code
```

If you want to see a list of the productinfo records, which may or may not have PRODUCTDETAIL records, use:

```
   SELECT a.product_code, b.received, b.issued
     FROM PRODUCTINFO a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.product_code,
                  SUM(t.qty_received) AS received, 
                  SUM(t.qty_issued) AS issued
             FROM PRODUCTDETAIL t 
            WHERE t.active = 1
         GROUP BY t.produce_code) b ON b.product_code = a.product_code
```

But the example looks like you might only need to use:

```
 SELECT t.product_code,
        SUM(t.qty_received) AS received, 
        SUM(t.qty_issued) AS issued
   FROM PRODUCTDETAIL t 
   WHERE t.active = 1
GROUP BY t.produce_code
```

Comment: Great thank you everyone for posting - problem solved and now takes less than one minute!! :D Awesome, really appreciated your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just group by inside the query and use an inner join

```
SELECT a.product_code, b.received, b.issued
FROM productinfo a
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT product_code, SUM(qty_received) AS received, SUM(qty_issued) AS issued
  FROM productdetail
  WHERE active = 1
  GROUP BY product_code) b on b.product_code = a.product_code
```